# How to use transactGet in dynamoDB with muliple parametres

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table name '**user**' with have partition key '**hashid**'.

**TABLE STRUCTURE**(user)

```
{

     "createtime": "2020-03-06 13:43:12",
     "hashid": "x_dt",
     "labdata": "x",
     "status": "stopped",
     "updatetime": "2020-03-06 13:43:12"
}
```

and code is

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: 'ap-south-1',
  maxRetries: 13,
  retryDelayOptions: { base: 200 }
});
 let params = {
        TransactItems: [
            {
                Get: {
                    TableName: 'user',
                    Key: {
                         "hashid":"x_dt",

                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    };

 let transactionRequest = await docClient.transactGet(params);
```

It is working fine when I used only 1 argument(hashid). Now, I want to filter based on status. 
how to use the status variable?